# EDT 20-20412-3 lcd rev.a pinout

Tags: lcd, pinout

I have salvaged an  EDT model 20-20412-3 lcd display I would like to use.  I have look for the PINOUT but can't find it anywhere.  It looks a lot like a ST7290 Graphical LCD Module (128x64px)  Maybe it uses the same pinout and Library?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pinout same as a 16x2? What you've described is a graphic display methinks, so the answer is 'not likely'.

Comment: OK, you edited away the question if pinouts are compatible. Now there is no question.

Answer (score 1):

That display is a graphical display, while the HD44780 compatibles are character-based displays.

They have different amount of pins.

There is no way these have compatible pinouts.